# Non-number theoretic formulation of Fermat's last theorem?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, analytic-number-theory, reference-works

We have dozens of non-number theoretic formulations of Riemann hypothesis. I was wondering if there are any non-number theoretic formulations of Fermat's last theorem? I am in particular curious about some analytic formulation?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you call "non-number theoretic". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Equivalent_statements_of_the_theorem) says,

Equivalent statement 4 – connection to elliptic curves: If $a, b, c$ is a non-trivial solution to $x^p + y^p = z^p$, $p$ odd prime, then $y^2 = x(x − a^p)(x + b^p)$ (Frey curve) will be an elliptic curve.

Examining this elliptic curve with Ribet's theorem shows that it does not have a modular form. However, the proof by Andrew Wiles proves that any equation of the form $y^2 = x(x − a^n)(x + b^n)$ does have a modular form. Any non-trivial solution to $x^p + y^p = z^p$ (with $p$ an odd prime) would therefore create a contradiction, which in turn proves that no non-trivial solutions exist.

In other words, any solution that could contradict Fermat's Last Theorem could also be used to contradict the Modularity Theorem. So if the modularity theorem were found to be true, then it would follow that no contradiction to Fermat's Last Theorem could exist either. As described above, the discovery of this equivalent statement was crucial to the eventual solution of Fermat's Last Theorem, as it provided a means by which it could be "attacked" for all numbers at once.

Comment: This not really an *equivalent* form of FLT.  It goes one way: if FLT is false then the modularity theorem is false.  There's no reason to expect that if the modularity theorem were false then it would lead to a counterexample to FLT.

Comment: @KCd, of course, you're right, and there are other problems with the Wikipedia account. For example, it's not really helpful to write about an elliptic curve "having" or "not having" a modular form. The whole essay could do with a rewrite.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right. 'Non-Theoretic' is ambigous but what I mean by this is formulations like we have for RH through integral equations, orthogonal polynomials etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are several [non-trivially-different] combinatorial formulations. In fact, there are many elementary reformulations — Ribenboim’s *Fermat’s Last Theorem For Amateurs* has a whole chapter of them, but it doesn’t include any analytic formulations (because of the scope of the book).

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look on this.